# export html table to excel with 'Datatables'

Tags: excel, datatables, export, html-table

I found this great jQuery library called 'DataTables' and I'd like to use the export to excel button.
This is their file-export preview page:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

I tried everything in the guide but I'm not sure why it won't work.

**The console log says:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.movie.setSheetName is not a function
```

Is this maybe a bug in the library itself?
I'm using version 1.1.2.
I tried adding the non-minified version.
It happens on this piece of code in the Buttons extension:

```
setSheetName: function(newText) {
    // set sheet name, for excel
    this.sheetName = newText;
    if (this.ready) {
        this.movie.setSheetName(newText);
    }
},
```

On the previous last line where is says `this.movie.setSheetName(newText);` it says that **"setSheetName" is not a function...**

It works on the examples/initialisation/export.html included in the Buttons folder.
I've even tried disabling all other scripts on the page, but it still won't work........ Only if I replace the whole page contents with the example page contents it works.
I'm not sure how to look for what is conflicting with the code.

**Any ideas on where or how to search for what's causing the bug?**

I've added the correct **dependencies:**

```
//CSS:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.jqueryui.css">
//JS:
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/frameworks/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code to **generate my table and initiate the DataTable:**

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#table2excel').DataTable({
        dom: 'frtipB',
        buttons:['excel']
    });
});
</script>

<table id="table2excel">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?
foreach($allluca01 as $results){
    $resultid = $results->ID;
    ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <? echo get_the_title($resultid); ?>
    </td>
</tr>


<?
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your code for how you build the table (HTML and JS)?

Comment: Yeah! I've just updated the question. Thank you! Do you have any experience with DataTables? BTW, the PHP gives a nice table, it shows up properly and the DataTable gets initiated, only I just can't use the 'export to excel' button...
It gives me the bug when I press "excel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason is probably because it needs the following dependencies, even though it's documented nowhere clearly...
Add these to the head scripts:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js
```